# ReferenceError: onclick function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've gotten a "ReferenceError: function is not defined on the saveRoute function". Everything seems right to me but i could not figure out the problem.

Here is the related codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var array = routeobj;
function saveRoute(){   
var json = JSON.stringify(array)
$.ajax({
    url : "http://192.168.1.9:11123/runornot/drawtrack",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json'
   data : {json:json}
       {"routeJson": json },
       console.log("hellohelloworldolr");
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    { //data - response from server
        console.log("checkin success"); },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    }});}
</script>
```

and in the html

```
 <a href="#" onClick="saveRoute();" id="savebtn" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a">Save</a>
```

Comment: if that is your code exactly as you have it, there are some syntax errors. These might be causing your method to never be properly defined.

Comment: Also you need to preventDefault()

Comment: @lemieuxster there are syntax errors? Can i know about these syntax errors. i really could not identify the errors.

Comment: @BrendanOng yeah, big ones... `dataType: 'json'` needs a comma after it, and then the three lines immediately afterword that are supposed to be the value for `data:` are seriously weird. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @AlexWayne i'm trying to send an object array into my servlet. The objects coordinates which i will then save as a route in the database.

Comment: Debugging is a fundamental skill of a software engineer. I recommend to [learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) so that you can solve such problems yourself. Then of course you have to learn the [basic JavaScript syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var array = routeobj;
function saveRoute(){   
var json = JSON.stringify(array) // <--- best practice would require a semicolon here
$.ajax({
    url : "http://192.168.1.9:11123/runornot/drawtrack",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json' // <--- missing a comma

    // the structure doesn't make any sense starting here...
    data : {json:json} // <--- should be a comma here?

    // missing property name?
       {"routeJson": json },

    // is this supposed to be the body of a function?
       console.log("hellohelloworldolr");

    // things start making sense again here...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    { //data - response from server
        console.log("checkin success"); },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    }});}
</script>
```